# Hyperparameter search with Gridsearch giving parameter values that don't work

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am running a hyperparameter search with scikit-learn's GridSearch using a CountVectorizer and a RandomForestClassifier. The hyperparameter search grid looks like this:

```
grid = {
    'vectorizer__ngram_range': [(1, 1)],
    'vectorizer__stop_words': [None, german_stop_words],
    'vectorizer__max_df': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
    'vectorizer__min_df': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10],
    'vectorizer__max_features': [None,100,1000, 1500],
    'classifier__class_weight': ['balanced', 'balanced_subsample', None],
    'classifier__n_jobs': [-1],
    'classifier__n_estimators': [100, 190, 250]
    
    }
```

The gridsearch runs until the end and gives me a best_params result. I have run it several times and different results come out. During the run I get these errors sometimes

```
  warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:548: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 330, in fit
    Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 292, in _fit
    X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 352, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 740, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "/root/complex_semantics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1213, in fit_transform
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df
```

Which I assume is normal since some values are not well-mixed. But a couple of times after getting the best params and running the model with them I then get an error telling me that the values of max_df and min_df are incorrect since the amount of documents selected with max_df is lower than the amount with min_df.

How come it runs correct during hyperparameter search with the same dataset and not with the normal run?

Any ideas? Is there a way to avoid this?

This is the code for the GridSearch

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())])

scoring_function = make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=grid, scoring=scoring_function, n_jobs=-1, cv=5)
grid_search.fit(X=train_text, y=train_labels)
print("-----------")
print(grid_search.best_score_)
print(grid_search.best_params_)
```

Answer (score 0):

The values in your `max_df` are smaller than in `min_df`.

The default `max_df` is `1.0`, which means *ignore terms that appear in more than `100%` of the documents*.

`min_df` is used for removing terms that appear too occasionally.

Let's see what that translates to in your case.

```
'vectorizer__max_df': [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
'vectorizer__min_df': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10],
```

Let's see an example.

- `max_df = 0.25` means "ignore terms that appear in more than `25%` of the documents"
- `min_df = 0.01` means "ignore terms that appear in less than `1%` of the documents".

The issue I am seeing is with `5` and `10` in `min_df`.

- `min_df = 5` means "ignore terms that appear in less than 5 documents".
- `min_df = 10` means "ignore terms that appear in less than 10 documents".

The error even tells you about this `ValueError: max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df` which probably comes from using `10` or `5` in `min_df` as you probably have less documents in total than those values.

So I would suggest to just sticking to float values(percentages) for both `max_df` and `min_df` and perhaps use the values `[0.01, 0.1, 0.2]` for `vectorizer__min_df`.